# Insert html code from react app into express

Tags: reactjs, express

I have an express app with the following domains (wildcard subdomains)

```
www.example.com
subdomain1.example.com
subdomain2.example.com
```

I also have in **cdn.example.com** a react app

I need to load that react app into subdomain2.example.com

basically I have some logic in the express app that checks if subdomain is equal to subdomain1 then it should load react app otherwise just print something in the page.

I was thinking about doing something like this to read the index.html from the cdn and return it into the express app

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.subdomains[0] === 'subdomain1') {
        request('http://cdn.example.com/index.html', function (error, response, body) {
            return res.status(200).send(body)
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(200).send('hello world')
    }
});
```

It works but I don't think this is the right way to do it. I only found examples of domains pointing directly to index.html from react apps.

My biggest problem is that the react app changes the hash on every build. that´s why I´m just grabbing the entire html React index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.subdomains[0] === 'subdomain1') {
        res.redirect('http://cdn.example.com/index.html')
    } else {
        return res.status(200).send('hello world')
    }
});
```